# Subquery in Laravel 4.2

Tags: subquery, create-table, laravel-4.2

I'm trying to write a subquery in Laravel 4.2 where to substract data from the subquery and then to build table1 with necessary age bands but I can't get it right.

The query is this:

```
  $var1= DB::table('table1')
            ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*), CASE
WHEN age >=0  AND age <=20 THEN '0-20' 
WHEN age >=21 AND age <=24 THEN '21-24'
WHEN age >=25 AND age <=29 THEN '25-29'
WHEN age >=30 AND age <=34 THEN '30-34'
WHEN age >=35 AND age <=39 THEN '35-39'
WHEN age >=40 AND age <=44 THEN '40-44'
WHEN age >=45 AND age <=49 THEN '45-49'
WHEN age >=50 AND age <=54 THEN '50-54'
WHEN age >=55 AND age <=59 THEN '55-59'
WHEN age >=60 AND age <=64 THEN '60-64'
WHEN age >=65 THEN 65+
END AS age"), 
   function ($query){
     $query->select(DB::raw("( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') <
     DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '00-%m-%d')) AS age FROM ...
   ) AS table1"));
            })
            ->groupBy('age')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this question using this link http://laravel.io/forum/12-23-2015-subquery-in-laravel-eloquent-or-query-builder and I build my query accordingly where table1 is not a real table in the DB but is created from the subquery. Here is the code:

```
$ageband = DB::table('table1')
            ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*),
          CASE
            WHEN age >=0  AND age <=20 THEN '0-20'
            WHEN age >=21 AND age <=24 THEN '21-24'
            WHEN age >=25 AND age <=29 THEN '25-29'
            WHEN age >=30 AND age <=34 THEN '30-34'
            WHEN age >=35 AND age <=39 THEN '35-39'
            WHEN age >=40 AND age <=44 THEN '40-44'
            WHEN age >=45 AND age <=49 THEN '45-49'
            WHEN age >=50 AND age <=54 THEN '50-54'
            WHEN age >=55 AND age <=59 THEN '55-59'
            WHEN age >=60 AND age <=64 THEN '60-64'
            WHEN age >=65 THEN '65+'
          END AS ageband"))
            ->from(DB::raw("( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') <
                        DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '00-%m-%d')) AS age FROM health_clients
          ) as table1"))
            ->groupBy('ageband')
            ->get();
```